# El contenido de mi Requests aparece vació

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy, beautifulsoup

estoy intentando realizar un scraper con python utilizando requests y beautifulsoup.

```
    url= "https://www.espanol.skyscanner.com/transporte/vuelos-desde/buea/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home"
response = requests.get(url)
src=response.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")
precios=soup.find_all("span", class_="from")
```

y nose por que no tengo contenido en mi variable "precios" . Mi idea es poder asignar dos variables "pais" "precio" para luego ponerle una condición. Muchas gracias. También si saben como rotar la vpn seria de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que sucede es que el contenido es traido por ajax.
puedes hacerlo haciendo una consulta directo al url que trae por ajax que esta en formato json:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url= "https://www.espanol.skyscanner.com/transporte/vuelos-desde/buea/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home"

## json url ##
url= "https://www.espanol.skyscanner.com/g/browseservice/dataservices/browse/v3/bvweb/PA/PAB/es-MX/destinations/BUEA/anywhere/anytime/?profile=minimalcityrollupwithnamesv2&include=image;holiday&apikey=8aa374f4e28e4664bf268f850f767535" 
# headers 
headers = {
    "referer": "https://www.espanol.skyscanner.com/transporte/vuelos-desde/buea/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
# hacemos el requests get
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
# pasamos a json
data = response.json()

# hacemos un loop
for pais in data["PlacePrices"]:
    # validamos que exista DirectPrice
    dprice = pais.get("DirectPrice")
    # validamos que exista IndirectPrice
    iprice = pais.get('IndirectPrice')

    # si existe IndirectPrice y DirectPrice
    if dprice != None and iprice != None:
        print(f"{pais['Id']}  {dprice} {iprice}  {pais['Name']} ")
    # solo existe DirectPrice
    elif dprice == None:
        print(f"{pais['Id']}  {iprice:<10}  {pais['Name']} ")
    # solo existe IndirectPrice
    else:
        print(f"{pais['Id']}  {dprice:<10}  {pais['Name']} ")
```

Comment: sos un genio @Bryro !!! muchisimass gracias, de verdad me ayudaste mucho. Te hago una sola pregunta mas, sabrías como realizar un scraping pero rotando la vpn proxy? o tal vez realizarlo con tor , nose estoy medio perdido en eso

Comment: @EmanuelLemos si te sirvio deverias confirmar la respuesta dandole a la gancho de aceptacion!

Comment: genial , ahi creo que lo hice. Perdon soy medio "nuevo" en el foro . esta bien ahi no ? me re sirvio muchas gracias

Comment: si, es para que no te quede abierta la pregunta. y puedas realizar otra mas adelante!

Comment: como estas? me podrias ayudar con el cambio de proxies?? intento hacerlo con el mismo link de pagina web... pero cuando hago un get(url, proxies= proxies (aca le intento agregar una lista que me bajo de otra web) , timeour=5) y no me lo toma , me podrias ayudar por favor